# How can we pass a parameter to an action through the route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass something to the `params` hash through the path. My code is:

**routes.rb**

```
get :search, controller: :restaurants
```

**restaurants_controller.rb**

```
before_action :force_json, only: :search

def search
    @restaurants = Restaurant.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%").limit(5)
end

private

    def force_json
      request.format = :json
    end
```

Due to the `before` action, we shouldn't need to refer to the path as `search.json`; `search` alone should be sufficient. However, when I try to pass a parameter `:q` to the `params` hash like this:

```
localhost:3000/search&q=A
```

I end up with this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/search&q=A"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query string is not structured correctly.

`localhost:3000/search?q=a`

More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure

Comment: Thanks so much! Helpful to see the other rules involved in structuring query strings

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you mean in query string you should pass it as

```
localhost:3000/search?q=A
```

Otherwise, you can put the parameter in your route definition

```
get 'search/:q'
```

Comment: Thank you! Embarrassingly misplaced ? for &